# JtextField Variable Grab and Use for Numerical Iteration from GUI

Tags: return, actionlistener, jtextfield, actionevent

this is my complete code for a small gui to take variables from user and return them to the rest of program(r.o.p) for calculations, however doesn't seem to be passing to r.o.p. and no output file is observerd.

Any help would be much appreciated, I think the problem is with the listener for the Draw New Graph command. Thanks

Code:

```
    import java.text.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    public class RungeKutta {

        // class to create slider and window

        private static File file1;

        public static double A(double v, double x, double wc, double beta) {
            return (-2 * beta * v - (Math.pow(wc, 2)) * Math.sin(x));
        }

        public static File getFile1() {
            return file1;
        }

        public static void setFile1(File file1) {
            RungeKutta.file1 = file1;
        }

        public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException, ParseException {


            createAndShowGUI();

        }

        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            //create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("RungeKutta");
            GridLayout first = new GridLayout(14,1);
            frame.setLayout(first);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            //Create, name and Populate TextField   
            JTextField PL = new JTextField("Pendulum Length", 20);
            //Set TextField to Uneditable. Each will have Empty Field Below For Variables   
            PL.setEditable(false);  
            //Set Textfield for user entered dat
            JTextField PLv = new JTextField();
            //Allow input from text field to be taken


            JTextField AD = new JTextField("Angular Displacement", 20);
            AD.setEditable(false);
                JTextField ADv = new JTextField();

            JTextField AV = new JTextField("Angular Velocity", 20);
            AV.setEditable(false);
            JTextField Avv = new JTextField();

            JTextField TS= new JTextField("Time Steps", 20);
            TS.setEditable(false);
            JTextField TSv = new JTextField();

            JTextField MT = new JTextField("Max Time", 20);
            MT.setEditable(false);
            JTextField MTv = new JTextField();

            JTextField V = new JTextField("Viscosity (0-1)", 20);
            V.setEditable(false);
            JTextField Vv = new JTextField();

            //Create Button to Restart and Button to take in Values for usage






        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,500));
        frame.getContentPane().add(PL, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(PLv, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(AD, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ADv, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(AV, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Avv, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(TS, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(TSv, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(MT, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(MTv, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(V, first);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Vv, first);
        JButton BNewGraph = new JButton("Draw New Graph"); //Button to restart entire drawing process
        frame.getContentPane().add(BNewGraph, first);
        //display the window
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        class intakegui implements ActionListener
        {

            public intakegui()
            {
                    BNewGraph.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
                    BNewGraph.setActionCommand("Click to Draw");               
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             double l = Double.parseDouble(PLv.getText());
             double xi = Double.parseDouble(ADv.getText());
             double vi = Double.parseDouble(Avv.getText());
             double dt = Double.parseDouble(TSv.getText());
             double n = Double.parseDouble(MTv.getText());
             double beta = Double.parseDouble(Vv.getText());



            SimpleDateFormat dform = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyysmH");
            Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String dstr = dform.format(d);
            String filename = ("result " + dstr + ".txt");
            file1 = new File(filename);
            PrintWriter savedValues = null;
            try {
                savedValues = new PrintWriter(filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            //declare variable for gravity and omega*c
            double g = 9.8;
            double wc = Math.sqrt(g / l);
            savedValues.println("#Initial Values Entered");
            savedValues.println("#" + l + "," + vi + "," + xi + "," + dt + "," + n
                    + "," + beta);
            double[] dispTime = new double[(int) n];
            double[] velTime = new double[(int) n];

            // let a = angular acceleration

            for (double j = 0; j < (int) n; j++) {
                // int time = 1;
                double k1v = dt * j * A(vi, xi, wc, beta);
                double k1x = dt * j * vi;

                double k2v = dt * j * A(vi, xi + (0.5 * k1x), wc, beta);
                double k2x = dt * j * (vi + (0.5 * k1v));

                double k3v = dt * j * A(vi, xi + (0.5 * k2x), wc, beta);
                double k3x = dt * j * (vi + (0.5 * k2v));

                double k4v = dt * j * A(vi, xi + k3x, wc, beta);
                double k4x = dt * j * (vi + k3v);

                xi += k1x / 6 + k2x / 3 + k3x / 3 + k4x / 6;
                vi += k1v / 6 + k2v / 3 + k3v / 3 + k4v / 6;

                dispTime[(int) j] = xi;
                velTime[(int) j] = vi;
                System.out.println(xi + "," + vi);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < (int) n; i++) {
                savedValues.println(dispTime[i] + " " + velTime[i]);
            }
            savedValues.close();
            System.out.println("File saved. File name: " + filename);

            }   
        }   
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add listener to your button. You need to add listener as below:

```
BNewGraph.addActionListener(new intakegui());
```

Now when user clicks on button, you would see the file.

Comment: Still doesn't work soory, I've tried adding the calculation to its own class and add that into the listener instead of intakegui but doesn't work either. A problem with static return types I think but I have no idea how to fix it